# Convert svg image to png in java by servlet

Tags: java, servlets, svg, png

Here, I am trying to send a SVG image to local server and in output I want to download that image in PNG / JPEG format.

While I have found some solutions but those are done by BATIK libraries, but in my Eclipse BATIK libraries are not supported , so I can't use the batik libraries.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: create a folder called lib inside your eclipse project, copy the BATIK library to the lib folder, right click on the libraray "jar" and select -> add to buildpath.

Comment: sir, where can I  found batik libraries??? @krzysztof Cichocki

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use batik library. Below is the code.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;
    import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
    import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    public class svg2png {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            //Step -1: We read the input SVG document into Transcoder Input
            //We use Java NIO for this purpose
            String svg_URI_input = Paths.get("chessboard.svg").toUri().toURL().toString();
            TranscoderInput input_svg_image = new TranscoderInput(svg_URI_input);        
            //Step-2: Define OutputStream to PNG Image and attach to TranscoderOutput
            OutputStream png_ostream = new FileOutputStream("chessboard.png");
            TranscoderOutput output_png_image = new TranscoderOutput(png_ostream);              
            // Step-3: Create PNGTranscoder and define hints if required
            PNGTranscoder my_converter = new PNGTranscoder();        
            // Step-4: Convert and Write output
            my_converter.transcode(input_svg_image, output_png_image);
            // Step 5- close / flush Output Stream
            png_ostream.flush();
            png_ostream.close();        
        }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Refer this: http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2012/12/Batik-Convert-SVG-PNG-Java-Program-Example.html

Comment: I also have this code but in my eclipse there is error of batik libraries. BATIK libraries are supported , for that what should I do??

Comment: Check for version compatibility. https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/34405-installing-batik-use-eclipse.html

Comment: I have added the BATIK libraries but the problem is still same .

Comment: this is not working in eclipse .
it generate the following errors:
and i have already imported these classes

Comment: Just for completeness (because the question asked for "image in PNG / JPEG format"): alternatively for PNGTranscoder you can use org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder to transform the SVG file into a jpg file.

Comment: bugs: 1. one needs to use try-with-resources for FileOutputStream for a correct code, 2. Java code style convention is to use method names like `convertSVGToPNG`.

Comment: And here are the official Batik docs: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html#howtousetranscoderAPI

Answer (score -6):

You can also convert svg to png format without the use of Batik Transcoder.

```
BufferedImage input_image = null; 
input_image = ImageIO.read(new File("Convert_to_PNG.svg")); //read svginto input_image object
File outputfile = new File("imageio_png_output.png"); //create new outputfile object
ImageIO.write(input_image, "PNG", outputfile);
```

By simply using the `ImageIO` library. Hope this will help!

Comment: nope, input_image is null in my case, seems that ImageIO silently fails to get any image readers